# Object Oriented Fundamentals in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have a simple table which has the following columns

```
Table 'Names'
id (PRIMARY KEY)
name (VARCHAR 250)
strikes (SMALLINT)
```

Under certain business rules (which are not relevant here), the 'strikes' against a particular 'id' will get incremented. I can write a very simple MySql statement to do that:

```
UPDATE TABLE names 
SET strikes = strikes + 1
WHERE id = $id
```

However, since the table has a corresponding business object with class named 'Names', I have to do this instead:

```
$objName = new Names($id);               //initiate an object with id = $id
$numStrikes = $objName->get("strikes");  //get the current strikes against this id
++$numStrikes;                           //increment the number of strikes
$objName->set("strikes",$numStrikes);    //set the strikes against id = $id
$objName->save();                        //save the object in underlying DB
```

The above "object oriented approach" is honestly feeling like I am trying to hold my nose by bringing my arm from behind my head! Is this really the right approach or is there a better way to do this? I would like to stick to OOP in PHP but only if it makes sense!

Comment: **stick to OOP in PHP but only if it makes sense** get the tattoo, or at least the t-shirt

Comment: `$objName->set('strikes', $objName->get('strikes') + 1);` for the win :)

Comment: I could certainly add a method to my 'Names' class called 'incrementStrikes'....but it would still need to load the object, read the current strikes, increment the strikes and then save the data back to the DB.....I am asking if this process can be improved upon in an OOP fashion or should I simply write the MySQL query mentioned above and "just get the job done"!

Comment: "stick to OOP in PHP but only if it makes sense get the tattoo, or at least the t-shirt".....I would certainly follow my own advice, but the problem is that it would take me weeks to determine if OOP is "making sense" or not...when would I actually write the damn code?!!

Comment: ALso be aware the OOP code has a possible race condition if for example two separate web requests call that code at the same time then it's possible one of the increments would get overwritten by the other.  This issue doesn't exist if you do the increment in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't make it object-oriented if it's only going to be simple. Although I'd suggest adding an `add_strike()` method to the `Names` class that will run that same script you ran.